# The problem is about sending email in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void SendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("fromemail", "From Me");
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("toemail", "To You");
            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add(toAddress);
            message.Subject = "Testing!";
            message.Body = "This is the body of a sample message";
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.host.com";
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.Send(message);
            statusLabel.Text = "Email sent.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "Coudn't send the message!\n"+ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

The error is

> "Failure sending mail."

I can not send any.
What is the problem?

innerexception is

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.39.109:587 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Comment: So what exception do you get (if any)?

Comment: Please include the output of the entire ex.ToString().  The actual problem is probably described in an inner exception and the entire exception output is needed to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the inner exception: 74.125.39.109:587 cannot be reached.

Make sure:

1. 74.125.39.109:587 actually has a SMTP server running
2. From the server running the code, make sure you can connect to that IP:Port (there isn't a firewall or virus scanner blocking the outgoing smtp connection attempt).

One way to test, is from that same server, open a telnet connection to 74.125.39.109:587.

Comment: Thank you.Yes it is working.I can send emails.The antivirus program blocked my socket.

Answer (score 3):

For an [`SmtpException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception%28VS.80%29.aspx), you *always* have to examine the inner exception through the [`Exception.InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property. Always.

Comment: This should have been a comment, you are not answering his question.

Comment: What is the rule when to post as an answer or as a comment?

Comment: A one liner that doesn't actually help the user directly should be a comment.

Comment: OK, I'll try to improve. I thought when posting a hyperlink it is usually better to avoid comments since links in answers can be formatted.

Comment: [Uwe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) - as you can see, they can be formatted in comments as well :)

Comment: Not the shortcut syntax. Just use the `[text](url)` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the try/catch and see what happens :-)

You can test locally first:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod='SpecifiedPickupDirectory'>
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\maildrop" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

More details:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/27/asp-net-using-pickup-directory-for-outgoing-e-mails.aspx

Comment: I did as you say it worked.But when i changed it to Network it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out all the smtp server settings and place the [mailSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in your app/web.config

Sometimes mail servers will not allow mail relaying.  In this case, you will need to set up a virtual smtp server.

[Relaying in IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d5ee6df6-5f9b-42ad-984b-3ce97fdfb50d.mspx?mfr=true)

If you are using windows server 2008, you will need to install the IIS 6 management console to configure relaying.

Answer (score 1):

Default SMPT port is 25. You are using 587, could this be the problem. Or is there a reason for using port?

Comment: Because i use gmail account for sending emails.That is why i used 587

Answer (score 1):

u have use 587 as the port....this is similar to gmail's smtp service port number....if ur using gmail smtp service...try use this...

host: smtp.gmail.com
port: 587

in network ceredentials give ur valid gmail username and its password...

also check ur internet connectivity

Answer (score 0):

**I remember i face similar problem the solution i find is:**

before:

`smtpClient.Send(message);`

Put this line:

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };`

BTW:

the port should be:
`smtp.Port = 25;`